# FB.api unexpected indentifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to acces the amount of people going on a public event in facebook. I've read through the docs of how to initialise the FB.api but when I try to run the code I get-

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on line 29 (var going)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dataButton').click(getFacebookData);
    $("input").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
           event.preventDefault();
           getFacebookData();
        }
    });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
       FB.init({
          appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
       });     
       $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
       FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
    });
 });

//variables --> array goes here


function getFacebookData() {
    //variables
    var url = $('#url').val();
    var going = FB.api('/'url'/attending', function(response){console.log(response)});
    $('#text').append(going);
};
```

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
var going = FB.api('/'url'/attending', function(response){console.log(response)});
```

to-

```
var going = FB.api('/'+url+'/attending', function(response){console.log(response)});
```

(note the **+** sign, to concatenate a string and a variable)